# How to acces other servlet's init-parameters or context's contex-parameters inside quartz jobs?

Tags: java, servlets, quartz-scheduler, init-parameters, context-param

I have defined my quartz job with the XML jobs configuration as in here example 2

http://www.mkyong.com/java/example-to-run-multiple-jobs-in-quartz/

I have other servlets wich have some init-params and my web app also has some context-params.

How do I access these parameters inside my job which implements the Job class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) One can basically access the servlet's context like this

in web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>quartz:scheduler-context-servlet-context-key</param-name>
    <param-value>ServletContext</param-value>
</context-param>
```

in code

```
    ServletContext MyServletContext = null;
    MyServletContext = (ServletContext) context.getScheduler().getContext().get("ServletContext");
```

2) And then another servlet's parameters like this

```
ServletContext.getServletRegistration("MyServlet").getInitParameter("MyInitParam");
```

Answer (score 0):

I see several options here.

Create a holder object that would just hold the information you want to access in your job.

```
public class ConfigHolder {
    static public Map importantData;
}
```

you would then initialize the data using the `servlet2` in its `init` method.

Schedule the job with JobDataMap like this

```
JobDetail jd = new JobDetail("yourjob", Scheduler.DEFAULT_GROUP, JobClass.class);
jd.getJobDataMap().put("config", configObject);
```